# sitemappath cross page postback

Tags: asp.net, cross-page-posting

my website uses cross page postback from page to page to access information from the previous page.

i am wondering if it is possible to do cross page postback when clicking on the links in a sitemappath as it seems it is simply doing a response.redirect which is causing the PreviousPage to be null.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the whole idea of Cross Page Posting was to allow postbacks to a page that is not the source page, and to do so you have to set the PostBackUrl property of a control. To my knowledge, the siteMapNode element doesn't have the PostBackUrl property. I'd imagine that only controls that have PostBackUrl exposed can take advantage of Cross Page Posting. But, hey, I've been wrong before!